# How to convert docx to doc and vice versa without using Aspose and installing OpenOffice java

Tags: java, apache-poi

So, I have a problem with converting my files. I can't install OpenOffice so can't use jodconverter. I've tried to use Apache POI but I wasn't able to copy all text formatting and other stuff. What is the better way?

P.S. Aspose isn't a way too, cause I can't buy it
P.P.S. May be the way is to use libre of open office portable. Tried it with JODConverter, but my app always stucks

Comment: You need a full product to do the conversion. The java libraries cannot do this on their own.

Comment: Hmm, and what about documents4j?

Comment: Well, try... you will learn a lot from this.

Comment: Sooo, I think I made it to work with documents4j

Comment: "documents4j is a Java library for converting documents into another document format. This is achieved by delegating the conversion to _any native application_ which understands the conversion of the given file into the desired target format. ".  You still need a native application to do it.

Comment: Ofc, I have office 2007 installed, so it's the way for me. Also JODconverter can use libreoffice or openoffice portable. Anyway, my problem is solved and all works well as I needed.

Comment: Please write up a good answer then, so others in the same situation (“future-yous”) can learn from your experiences.

Answer (score 0):

```
    IConverter converter = LocalConverter.builder()
            .workerPool(20, 25, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .processTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
    File doc = new File("PathToDoc");
    File docx = new File(doc.getName() + "x");
    converter
            .convert(doc).as(DocumentType.DOC)
            .to(docx).as(DocumentType.DOCX)
            .execute();
    converter.shutDown();
```

But still you are needed office installed. If you want to use Open or Libre you can use JODConverter, it's quite similar